# Interval determination with mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, homework

I am given the solution y=yo/(1-yo x^2). If yo>0, the solution is valid only on ( 
 -1/sqrt(yo), 1/sqrt(yo) ). How is this determined? I need a proof like answer and I need it programmed in Mathematica. Can you help? Thank you .

Comment: Asking for help suggests that you've made a start on your problem yourself and need some assistance to finish it and to remove the rough edges.  Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `Reduce[]`.  I'm not sure what a "proof-like answer" would look like.  Unless it's `FindEquationalProof[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the denominator equal to zero gives the points where your function goes to infinity.  You can use Mathematica (or algebra) to find those points where `1-y0 x^2` is zero:

```
g[x_,y0_]:=y0/(1-y0 x^2);
Assuming[{y0>0}, Solve[1/g[x,y0]==0,x]
```

This gives

```
{{x -> -1/Sqrt[y0]},{x -> 1/Sqrt[y0]}}
```

The solution is valid between these two points.

Here is an example with `y0=9`.  The solution between `-1/3` and `1/3` is finite, and approaches infinity at both ends of the interval.  The function also exists to the left and to the right of the interval.  Perhaps you could say why you believe `y` does not exist there also.

```
 y0 = 9; Plot[g[x, y0], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: The function y=y(x).]